# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find storage device at null Android

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I have a problem with memory access. The strangest thing is that this error is not even find in the internet. This bug happened on device with android 11.

The method with which the problem is related:

```
void  initSaveDataFolder(){
            if(SecurityPreferences.getAutoChosseFolder())
                for (File file : App.get().getExternalCacheDirs()) {
                    try {
                        if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file)) {
                            //System.out.println("getExternalCacheDirs is "+new Gson().toJson(file));
                            StatFs stat = new StatFs(file.getAbsolutePath());
                            long bytesAvailableInSdCard = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
                            StatFs stat2 = new StatFs( App.get().getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
                            long bytesAvailableInInternalMemory = (long)stat2.getBlockSize() *(long)stat2.getAvailableBlocks();
                            if(bytesAvailableInSdCard>bytesAvailableInInternalMemory)   SecurityPreferences.setIsSaveDataOnUsb(true);
                            else  SecurityPreferences.setIsSaveDataOnUsb(false);
                            System.out.println("memoryes is "+ bytesAvailableInSdCard+" "+bytesAvailableInInternalMemory);
                            SecurityPreferences.saveAutoChosseFolder(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }catch (NullPointerException e){
                        SecurityPreferences.setIsSaveDataOnUsb(false); break;
                    }
                }
        }
```

Permissions related to storage access:

```
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And Error stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.estvisx.ma/com.estvisx.ma.ui.splash.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find storage device at null
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3431)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find storage device at null
       at android.os.Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(Environment.java:1202)
       at com.estvisx.ma.ui.splash.SplashActivity.initSaveDataFolder(SplashActivity.java:297)
       at com.estvisx.ma.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:83)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1534)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3404)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I tried to search about this problem whole day, but i didnt find anything. I just have no idea.

Comment: `have a problem with memory access.` Not with memory but storage access i think. Further you did not tell what your code should do. So please tell that at the first lines of your post.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation for `getExternalCacheDirs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalCacheDirs()) clearly states that it returns an array of `File` containing:

> File[] - the absolute paths to application-specific directories. Some
> individual paths may be null if that shared storage is not currently
> available. The first path returned is the same as
> getExternalCacheDir().

So you need to check each entry in the returned array for `null`. In your case, you are getting a `null` entry in the array which causes this exception.